# In Angular 2 how do we handle dependecies of resolve observable?

Tags: angular, observable, resolve

How do I resolve **this.personnelAPIService.mainID** before Person is resolved.

```
export class PersonResolver implements Resolve<Person[]>{

    constructor(private commonAPIService: CommonAPIService,
        private personnelAPIService: PersonnelAPIService) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Person[]> {
        return this.commonAPIService.getPersons(**this.personnelAPIService.mainID**);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used APP_INITIALIZER to retrieve parameters that were required during resolve of route parameters.